# What is difference between RequestContextFilter and OncePerRequestFilter in spring?

Tags: java, spring

Spring documentation for Class [RequestContextFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) mentions that this filter exposes the request to the current thread, through both LocaleContextHolder and RequestContextHolder.

Can someone please explain how this is different from OncePerRequestFilter class, and how can I implement such a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [RequestContextFilter source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.java#L97).
It actually extends `OncePerRequestFilter` and implements the abstract method `doFilterInternal` to [initializes LocaleContextHolder and RequestContextHolder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.java#L113). After this, the Locale and the RequestAttributes can be retrieved anywhere in the current thread.

If you want to declare `RequestContextFilter` in you app, you can just declare it as a bean :

```
@Bean 
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
  return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

You can also register the filter in the `web.xml` if you have one.